# Fancybox hideOnContentClick does not work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to integrate fancybox, with the following setting. I am linking a group of links on my page. On each page, there is an "add to cart" button, which triggers an AJAX event to add the product to the shopping cart, whenever this button is clicked, fancybox closes, but I would like to have it stay. I have used hideOnContentClick, but doesn't seem to work. Please help me. I have also tried going to the jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js to comment out the belows, but still doens't work:

```
        if (currentOpts.hideOnContentClick) {
            content.bind('click', $.fancybox.close);
        }
```

Here below is my script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'overlayColor'      : '#5B8FE2',
            'overlayOpacity'    : '0.2',
            'centerOnScroll' : 'true',
            'scrolling'         : 'no',
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'outside',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'height'            : '500',                    
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Product ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });
                               });
</script>
```

Comment: you mean fancybox closes on clicking inside the box or out of fancybox..

Comment: @Sudhir: if you have overlay, then you cannot click any link outside the box so I guess he means he clicks inside the box. - Matt: got any link?